# trying to write a code to print as many asterisks as the number it represents in given string?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out how to turn make it print asterisks next to the numbers in the table in this manner:

```
Element Value  Histogram
0        19    *******************
1         3    ***
2        15    ***************
```

I just started java and haven't got used to it yet, thank you!

Comment: You can use a `for` loop. Also, in Java 11 the `String` class has a [`repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) function.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) { System.out.print('*'); }`

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: lass Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  int arr[] = {19,3,15,7,11,9,13,5,17,1};
        int i;
  int w= -1;
  System.out.println("Elements\tvalue\thistogram");
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   w+=1;
   System.out.println(w +"                "+ arr[i] +"        "+ "*");
  }

 }
}//this is my code so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using `System.out.printf`.

```
int[] vals = {19,3,15,23,1};
System.out.printf("Element Value  Histogram%n");
for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-7s%4s    %s%n", i, vals[i], "*".repeat(vals[i]));
}
```

Prints

```
Element Value  Histogram
0        19    *******************
1         3    ***
2        15    ***************
3        23    ***********************
4         1    *
```

Comment: thank you, I figured that for loop is the way, but hadn't got any idea how to implement it, this was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. You can use `for loop` or `String.repeat()`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        printHistogram(new int[] { 19, 3, 15 });
    }

    public static void printHistogram(int[] arr) {
        System.out.println("Element Value Histogram");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.format("%-7d", i);
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.format("%-5d", arr[i]);
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println("*".repeat(arr[i]));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much! this is exactly how i wanted it to be!